# smallest integer contained in sublattice $\Rightarrow$ $L'=[q,r\tau+s]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, integer-lattices

Let $L'$ be a sublattice of the lattice $[1,\tau]$ in a imaginary quadratic field. Reminder: a lattice $L$ consists of the $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of $1$ and $\tau$, with $\{1,\tau \}$ linear independent over $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, in general a sublattice $L'$ of $L$ is of the form $[a \tau + b, c \tau + d]$.

I need to prove that if

- $[L:L']=|ad-bc|$ is of finite index (=determinant)
- and $q$ is the smallest positive integers contained in $L'$

then $L'$ is of the form $[q, r\tau + s]$ for some suited integers $r$ and $s$.

---

I did the following... say we have a linear combination

$$ q = \lambda(a \tau + b) + \mu(c \tau +d) = (\lambda a + \mu c) \tau + (\lambda b + \mu d)$$

Then $(\lambda a + \mu c)=0$ implies $\lambda=-kc$ and $\mu=ka$ for some integer $k$.

Now, the equation becomes

$$q = (-kbc+kad) = k \det(ad-bc)$$

Since $q$ must be minimal $k=1$, and $q=|ad-bc|=\det(L')$... not sure how to proceed...

Comment: I think you should remove the tag lattice-orders.

Comment: why exactly? an order in my textbook is: subring of $K$, contains $1$, finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}$-module, contains a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for the field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$? the fractional ideals of this order $\mathcal{O}$ can be considered as lattices (since they have rank $2$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module)

Comment: but I now see that this subforum uses "order" in the sense of "partial order" etc.